# Как узнать текущее значение suspendState?

Tags: c#

Есть код, который включает или выключает режим сна и гибернации

```
Application.SetSuspendState(параметры);
```

Но не могу найти пример, как узнать текущее состояние для `SuspendState`.

Грубо говоря, хочу показывать кнопку "отключить режим сна", если он включен и наоборот прятать, если выключен.

Comment: Ну, эээ, при вызове этой функции система переходит в сон/гибернацию. При этом вы никакую кнопку показать не можете. И отключить режим сна, пока вы в нём находитесь, вы тоже не можете.

Comment: @VladD Я видимо сложно выразился. 
В системе может стоять "настройка" о том, что переходить в сон\гибернацию через N минут. 
Я хочу сделать кнопку, которая эту настройку отключает. Но кнопка должна быть активна только в том случае, если эта настройка еще не "сброшена".

Comment: По идее вам [сюда](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373163(v=vs.85).aspx) через P/Invoke. Ну или WMI наверняка тоже умеет.